# pandas: read_csv combined date-time columns as index into a dataframe

Tags: pandas, data-analysis

I have a csv file which contains date and time stamps as two of the columns. I am using pandas `read_csv` to read the contents into a dataframe. My ultimate goal is to plot time series graphs from the data.

```
!head vmstat.csv
wait_proc,sleep_proc,swapped_memory,free_memory,buffered_memory,cached_memory,swapped_in,swapped_out,received_block,sent_block,interrups,context_switches,user_time,sys_time,idle_time,wait_io_time,stolen_time,date,time
0,0,10896,3776872,380028,10284052,0,0,6,16,7716,4755,3,1,96,0,0,2012-11-01,08:59:27
0,0,10896,3776500,380028,10284208,0,0,0,40,7471,4620,0,0,99,0,0,2012-11-01,08:59:32
0,0,10896,3749840,380028,10286864,0,0,339,19,7479,4704,20,2,77,1,0,2012-11-01,08:59:37
0,0,10896,3747536,380028,10286964,0,0,17,118,7488,4638,0,0,99,0,0,2012-11-01,08:59:42
0,0,10896,3747452,380028,10287148,0,0,0,24,7489,4676,0,0,99,0,0,2012-11-01,08:59:47


df = read_csv("vmstat.csv", parse_dates=[['date','time']])
f = DataFrame(df, columns=[ 'date_time',  'user_time', 'sys_time', 'wait_io_time'])

In [3]: f
Out[3]:
date_time               user_time  sys_time     wait_io_time
0  2012-11-01 08:59:27          3         1             0
1  2012-11-01 08:59:32          0         0             0
2  2012-11-01 08:59:37         20         2             1
3  2012-11-01 08:59:42          0         0             0
4  2012-11-01 08:59:47          0         0             0
```

So far, we could read the data correctly and `date_time` is combined in the DataFrame. There are issues if I try to used the `date_time` from `df` as index. Specifying `index = df.date_time` gives all `NaN` values:

```
dindex = f['date_time']
print dindex
g = DataFrame(f, columns=[ 'user_time', 'sys_time', 'wait_io_time'], index=dindex)

In [7]: g
Out[7]:
0    2012-11-01 08:59:27
1    2012-11-01 08:59:32
2    2012-11-01 08:59:37
3    2012-11-01 08:59:42
4    2012-11-01 08:59:47
Name: date_time  <---- dindex
g:
                 user_time  sys_time  wait_io_time
date_time                                             
2012-11-01 08:59:27        NaN       NaN           NaN
2012-11-01 08:59:32        NaN       NaN           NaN
2012-11-01 08:59:37        NaN       NaN           NaN
2012-11-01 08:59:42        NaN       NaN           NaN
2012-11-01 08:59:47        NaN       NaN           NaN
```

As you see, the column values are coming out as all `NaN`s. How do I get correct values as in the intermediate `f` frame?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to use [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html):

```
df1 = df.set_index('date_time')
```

Which selects the column `'date_time'` as an index for the new DataFrame.

.

*Note: The behaviour you are coming across in the DataFrame constructor is demonstrated as follows:*

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1,2],[3,4]])
df1 = pd.DataFrame(df, index=[1,2])

In [3]: df1
Out[3]: 
    0   1
1   3   4
2 NaN NaN
```

Comment: great, thanks! Now I am getting the correct format. I still need to debug why df1.plot is failing with the "object has no attribute 'ordinal'" error.

Comment: That should probably be a separate question, it should plot df with a timeseries as an index without a problem... :s

Comment: thanks, I am doing some initial tries, by installing a newer version of matplotlib. Will submit a new qn if all fails.

Answer (score 0):

I could get a workaround by the following code:

```
    up = f.pivot_table('user_time', rows='date_time')
    sp = f.pivot_table('sys_time', rows='date_time')
    wp = f.pivot_table('wait_io_time', rows='date_time')
    u=pandas.DataFrame(up)
    u['sys_time']=sp
    u['wait_io_time']=wp
    my_colors = ["#FF6666", "#00CC33", "#44EEEE"] 
    print u
```

Out:

```
                           user_time    sys_time  wait_io_time
    date_time                                          
    2012-11-01 08:59:27          3         1          0
    2012-11-01 08:59:32          0         0          0
    2012-11-01 08:59:37         20         2          1
    2012-11-01 08:59:42          0         0          0
    2012-11-01 08:59:47          0         0          0
```

There should be more straightforward ways to achieve this, but I am newB in pandas.

Moreover, the u.plot() functions fails in plotting a time series graph. "AttributeError: 'numpy.int64' object has no attribute 'ordinal'" So waiting to hear from others for a better solution.